# Android TextView gone/not visible

Tags: android

I have a `TextView` defined that works perfectly in the emulator. The View is only shown if a switch is checked. In the emulator, this works as designed. On my phone there is nothing displayed.

It is a timer, so in the update method I did a `setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE)` to make sure it is displayed, however nothing appears.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: The code is to large to share, i could share only the methods involved, but that would not be helpful anyway. I don't think it is an error in the code anyway, it works perfect in the emulator

Comment: we don't need the entire codebase, show us how you're referencing the view, maybe the text view XML code itself and perhaps how you're displaying that view/fragment/activity (just to make sure you're actually displaying the correct screen)

Comment: I could show you this. But as it is working perfectlly in the emulator, so I don't think it is such a newbie mistake. I need to know why it is working perfect in the emulator but not on my phone